# CDC/ACM device driver for windows CE 5.0

Tags: windows-ce

Microsoft gives a free CDC/ACM driver from windows CE 6.0. However, there is no CDC/ACM driver for windows CE 5.0. Is there any tutorial or any website that can help me to write CDC/ACM driver code for windows CE 5.0?

Comment: If you have access to Microsoft Platform Builder, you might be able to backport the CE 6.0 driver to 5.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercial CDC driver with WinCE 5 support : http://www.thesycon.de/deu/usb_cdcacm_ce.shtml